# UseExceptionHandler("/error") in Blazor WebAssembly hosted application

Tags: .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am implementing a Blazor WebAssembly hosted application, where I want to use a global exception handler in the backend project, which catches all unhandled exceptions, handles them and finally sends a Problem back to the client.

The ErrorController looks as follows:

```
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    private ErrorResponse _errorResponse = null;

    [Route("/error")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Error()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var exception = context.Error;

        var exceptionType = exception.GetType();

        if (exceptionType == typeof(CustomException))
        {
            var customException = (CustomException) exception;
            _errorResponse.Message = customException.Message;
            _errorResponse.StatusDescription = customException.StatusDescription;
            _errorResponse.Status = customException.StatusCode;
        }


        if (_errorResponse != null)
            await SendError();

        // Send Problem for fallback
        return Problem(exception.Message);

    }

    private Task SendError()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = _errorResponse.Status;

        return HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(_errorResponse.ToString());
    }
```

The controller is registered as the ExceptionHandler in Startup.Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Does not work
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
```

Although I could not find any hints, that this is not supported within Blazor WebAssembly hosted projects, the ErrorController is never called when a unhandled exception occures, the Exceptions are just rethrown an the application stops.

Is there a clarification which middlewares are supported inside hosted Blazor WebAssembly server projects?